# How to use sub-pattern frequencies to calculate the authenticity the main pattern

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, combinations

I'm trying to determine the probability that something is real by comparing the frequency of the sub-permutations it contains.

Here is an example: You want to guess whether or not a random symbol is a real Chinese character or something made up, but you do not have a Chinese dictionary or a speaker to help you. You only have the following information:

1. A list of percentage frequencies for how often each individual glyph appears throughout all the total Chinese characters.
2. A list of percentage frequencies for how often any two glyphs appear *together* throughout the language.
3. A list of percentage frequencies for how often any total number of glyphs appears (in a single character) throughout the language.

Pretend that `@#$%&Ø€‡` are the only 8 unique glyphs in the language.
Pretend that `@#%` is a character. We have no way to look up `@#%`, but we know...

1. A. *u* percent of all glyphs are `@`.  
   B. *v* percent of all glyphs are `#`. 
   C. *w* percent of all glyphs are `%`.
2. A. *x* percent of all characters contain `@#` 
   B. *y* percent of all characters contain `#%`
3. *z* percent of all characters have 3 total glyphs.

Assume "the test" contains an equal number of real and fake symbols, so if you just guess randomly you should be correct roughly half the time.

Can this information be used to mathematically increase the accuracy of a guess on whether or not a randomly selected symbol is real or not?
What factors contribute to the accuracy of the predictions? (I think it will matter a lot how many total glyphs there are, and probably the distribution of frequencies for each pair...)

Any advice on how to do this would be much appreciated. I've been trying to research it myself but I don't even know what the name is for this type of mathematics.

Comment: You've only specified half of the problem, the statistics of the real characters. Not much can be said without also knowing the statistics of the fake characters.

Comment: @joriki Can you be more specific about what statistics you need to know? Half the words "tested" will be fake. The fake characters will be comprised of real/known glyphs. Does that make sense? In other words the fake characters are comprised of the same set of glyphs that make real ones.

Comment: But for all you've said so far, they could have exactly the same statistics as the real ones, and then obviously we couldn't tell them apart; so you need to tell us something that allows us to distinguish them.

Comment: @joriki I do not believe there is any way to differentiate them 100% accurately. A perfectly "well-formed" fake one cannot be differentiated at all. So my goal is just to figure out a mathematical way to *improve* the accuracy of the guess. For example, let's say there is a pair of glyphs that *never* occur in conjunction with one another, or very very rarely. I think it's statistically "smarter" to guess that is a fake one, right? And one with all common features is more likely to be real, right? It might not be. But I want to make the smartest guess based on limited info. Does that help?

Comment: Another way to think about it is that there are a set of features that NEVER happen, and these can be used to definitively identify a fake if those occur. For example, in English spelling, no words contain the sequence: "bklzd" so a robot can very easily guess that it is not a real word without consulting a dictionary. There are also features that are very very rare. The presence of one probably makes it statistically more likely to be fake. The presence of multiple rare features should increase the chances it's fake right?

Comment: @joriki If it's helpful, in my real-world use-case I can compile many instances of the fakes... which theoretically would mean that I could generate statistics about the fakes myself. Does that help?

Comment: Yes, that would definitely help. You basically want to calculate the probabilities $p_r$ and $p_f$ of a certain character arising from the real process and the fake process; the prior probabilities are equal, so the probability for the character to be real is simply $p_r/(p_r+p_f)$. To calculate $p_f$ you need the statistics of the fakes. You're right of course that if $p_r=0$, then the result is $0$ independent of $p_f$.

Comment: @jorikiThis sounds promising... how can I combine and compare multiple features of a single character. For example, multiple glyph permutations are present in any single character, so I'd want somehow factor in multiple *P*'s right?

Comment: @joriki In anticipation... I went a head and compiled frequency stats for the fakes based on 100s of thousands of sample fakes. So I now have analogous stats for fakes to compare. But I still don't know how to mathematically bundle the frequencies of multiple features for a single character.